# Append the date from the first line of text file to the beginning of each other line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, append

I am trying to append the first line of text (the Date) to the beginning of each line in the rest of the text file. Can anyone help ? I'm using a bash to extract the data into the text file displayed. (completely New to this)

[Text File as discussed above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzDX0.png)

Current text file :

```
Sun Apr 7 14:16:30 
Host: 192.168.1.3; Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.5; Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.6; Status: Up
```

I want the text file to read:

```
Date (from first line); Host: 192.168.1.3; Status: Up
Date (from first line); Host: 192.168.1.5; Status: Up
Date (from first line); Host: 192.168.1.6; Status: Up
```

Comment: Please put a sample in the question. Also you should show your attempt, in the form of code, here.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Does this question still require more information? Apologies, this is my first time...

Comment: The only thing still missing to make it a good question for this forum is your attempt to solve it yourself, no matter how far off the mark you feel they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below `awk` would help :

```
awk 'NR==1{Date="Date" FS $0 ";" FS}NR!=1{print Date $0}' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
Date Sun Apr 7 14:16:30; Host: 192.168.1.3; Status: Up
Date Sun Apr 7 14:16:30; Host: 192.168.1.5; Status: Up
Date Sun Apr 7 14:16:30; Host: 192.168.1.6; Status: Up
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -v OFS='; ' 'NR==1{d=$0;next}{print d,$0}' file
```

Comment: You could also define `OFS='; '` and then `print d, $0` -- a little easier to read.

Comment: or easier to read: `awk '{if (NR==1) {date=$0} else {print date "; " $0}}' file`

Comment: @Cyrus that doesn't even look like awk

Comment: @oguzismail: Yeah, it's too easy ;)

Comment: @Cyrus anyway let your comment stay there maybe it helps op understand better if he is not familiar with awk

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1d;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/Date \2; \1/' file
```

Make a copy of the first line.

Delete the first line.

Append the first line to the current line.

Re-arrange the first line to the be in front of the current line and to be preceded by the literal `Date` and followed by `;`

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk, of respect to the 1st line #

```
 awk 'NR==1{a=$0;next}{print "Date "a,$0}' d
```

of respect to the pattern

```
awk '$0~/\s*(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)/{a=$0;next}{print "Date "a,$0}' d
```